# Android: transfer computed results from a service to an activity

Tags: android, mobile, android-activity, android-service

Firstly I may say that I know there are a lot of resources dealing with the communication between services and activities, I have also read the service-related part of the android developer guide. However, I'm still not sure about the best approach in my case.

When it comes to the communication between services and other components (like activities), *bound services* are described as the solution in most cases. But from my unterstanding, the use of a bound service always results in a request/response-model - an activity invokes a method on the service (request) and gets a return value (response). The android dev guide calls this a client/server-model.

In my scenario, a service generates a list of POJOs on a regular basis, but not exactly predictable (let's say every 1.5 - 2 seconds). Every time this happens, the list should be transferred to an activity in order to display it on the screen. In my opinion, a bound service is not the solution here, since my scenario does not match the request/response-model. In fact, the activity is passive and not really aware of the service. Of course I could use a polling strategy together with a bound service, but imho this is not the best approach in my case.

What would you recommend? I found solutions using a BroadcastReceiver in the activity (the service acts as sender), is this the only way or are there any other approaches? Or do I have a wrong unterstanding of bound services and they are not limited to request/response-scenarios?

**edit:**

As I already mentioned, a new list (java.util) is generated every 1.5-2 seconds by the service and should immediately passed to the activity. Such a list contains 20-25 POJOs that represent model objects; they contain 5 Strings and 3 integers each.
Just to give you a feeling of the complexity.

Is the BroadcastReceiver adequate for this amount of data and frequency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say, BroadcastReceiver is the best approach for this as compare to other options like handler, it would be create problem when large amount of calls would be occur. BroadcastReceiver will work fine because the flow of its working. I have worked with this, and I have got good result.